# Missing "ember simple auth" initializer in ember cli project

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember project (driven by Ember CLI ver 0.0.46) and I added latest Ember Simple Auth (ver 0.6.6) following the instruction on the https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth. 
However I don't get the Ember Simple Auth initializer which is supposed to be generated when I build the project.

Any ideas why this happens or suggestions how to manually generate it are welcome.

Comment: Did you run the generator as described here https://github.com/simplabs/ember-cli-simple-auth ?

Comment: Yes, I followed the instructions (one more time) but the initializer is still missing.
What I noticed though is that the instructions suggest to configure Ember Simple Auth this way:

  window.MyAppENV = {{ENV}};
+ window.ENV = window.MyAppENV;
  window.EmberENV = window.MyAppENV.EmberENV;

however my index.html file looks like this:

    <script>
      window.EmberENV = {{EMBER_ENV}};
    </script>

Could this be because of mismatch between the two (even though latest) versions?

Anyway, I guess the initializer should be created at the "ember generate ember-cli-simple-auth" step

Comment: The configuration doesn't affect the presence of the initializer.

Comment: Is it possible to have an initializer created with latest Ember Simple Auth posted here? I could manually adapt it for my project (if any changes are needed).

Comment: You can get the initializer from here: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-cli-simple-auth/blob/master/app/initializers/simple-auth.js. However I wouldn't recommend adding that manually as if the npm package doesn't work for you you should find out why that is as it might indicate some general problem.